# Is there a C# function in unity to detect a certain type of gameObject within a set range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im programming a survival game, and i want enemies to target the nearest player if they are within a specific range (e.g. 10m). Is there a function to detect the nearest player so i can program the attacks and movements?

Ive tried assigning the player and Going with a simple GameObject.LookAt but this doesnt allow for multiple players to be targeted, and i only want the player to be targeted within a certain range.

Comment: well you can do a spherecast to see if theres players inside aarea, or for each through all players and pick nearest..

Comment: Im fairly new to all this programming stuff, is that simply "gameObject.sphercast(10.0f)? Sorry if this is a stupid question im just having trouble finding an answer

Comment: no its a physics thing - th eunity documentation is very helpful

Comment: If you have a list of players, you can just iterate over them and calculate the distance. I wouldn't use a physics functionality when a simple distance calculation can do the trick.

Comment: I dont mean to be a pain, but could you dumb that down into beginner terms?

Comment: I suppose you have List<Player> or Player[] somewhere, maybe in a central game manager. You could use this list and iterate over the items in a for loop and check the distance between the players position and the enemies position. Using a spherecast will give you a similar list, but it is probably cheaper to just use an existing list instead of generating a new one.

Comment: Also, I don't think that this question suits StackOverflow. What you probably need is a mentor or a group of people to help with those questions, because the correct answer to the question is: No, Unity does not have that functionality, you have to make it yourself.

Comment: spherecast vs itteration depends how many enemies there are too, but thats something to profile and decide on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy. You can also implement it with sphere cast as suggested in the comments by @BugFinder . But, I will suggest the simple GameObject.Find approach.

First you should make a Player Monobehaviour and attach it to all the players.

```
public class PlayerMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Implement you player code here
}
```

Then In your enemy's monobehaviour - to find the nearest Player, you add the following code.

```
public class EnemyMono : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Your custom code here...

    private PlayerMono[] allPlayers; // This list should be cached bcz it has a little bit of overhead which makes it non-feasible to be called everytime.

    private PlayerMono GetNearestPlayer(Vector3 enemyPosition)
    {
        if (allPlayers  == null)
        {
            allPlayers = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<PlayerMono>();
            // otherwise do the following if you dont have a PlayerComponent and change PlayerMono references with GameObject
            // allPlayers = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerTag");
        }

        // Make sure to not cache the following array as it will not take into account the updated positions of the Player.
        Vector3[] allPlayersPositions = allPlayers.Select(player => player.transform.position).ToArray();

        PlayerMono nearestPlayer = allPlayers[GetNearestPlayerIndex(transform.position, allPlayersPositions)];
        return nearestPlayer;
    }

    // You need to install the Burst Package for this. If it confuses you,
    // simply comment the [BurstCompile]. It won't have any effect on the result of the code.
    // I just tend to do this as a habit for such functions where i am looping over vectors or other such types.
    [BurstCompile]
    private int GetNearestPlayerIndex(Vector3 enemyPosition, Vector3[] allPlayersPositions)
    {
        Vector3 nearestPosition = Vector3.positiveInfinity;
        int nearestPlayerIndex = 0;

        int currentIndex = 0;

        foreach (var playerPosition in allPlayersPositions)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(enemyPosition, playerPosition) < nearestPosition.magnitude)
            {
                nearestPosition = playerPosition;
                nearestPlayerIndex = currentIndex;
            }

            currentIndex++;
        }

        return nearestPlayerIndex;
    }
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the nearest player like :

```
PlayerMono nearestPlayer = GetNearestPlayer();
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nearestPlayer.transform.position) <= 10f)
{
    AttackPlayer(nearestPlayer); // implement it according to your needs.
}
else
{
    JustRelax(); // Exhibit Idle behaviour
}
```

Comment: If already using Linq anyway you could rather continue and use `FindObjectsOfType<PlayerMono>().OrderBy(o => (transform.position - o.tranaform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();`